# Java- reading from .data files

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io

I'm having a couple of problems setting up a system to read data into a Java program from two .data files...

I'm using Eclipse as my IDE, and have created the project in the folder where the two .data files are that I want to use. I've only just started this project, so I am still very much at its beginning...

The two .data files are: car.data and owner.data, and they are all that I have to start the project.

I've created a few classes: Owner.java, Car.java and ReadFile.java (to read the data from the .data files).

At present, my Owner.java file looks like this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Owner {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ReadFile rf = new ReadFile("Owner.data");
    rf.read("Owner.data");

}
File f;
public String id;
public String lastName;
public String firstName;
public String street;
public String city;

public void readOwner() throws FileNotFoundException{
    //File f = new File("Smart Stream Associate Software Engineer (Java) - Bristol/assessment/src/Owner.java");
    //InputStream IS = new FileInputStream(f);
}

}
```

My Car.java file looks like this:

```
public class Order {

public String orderID;
public String orderNo;
public String personID;


}
```

and my ReadFile.java file looks like this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile {
String[] columns = new String[]{"personID", "lastName", "firstName", "street", "city"};
String[] data = new String[100];

public void read() throws IOException{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("Person.data");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;

    int i = 0;
    while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
        data[i] = line;
        System.out.println(data[i]);
        i++;
    }
    br.close();

    String[] dataNew = new String[i];
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, dataNew, 0, i);
    data = dataNew;
    System.out.println("Data length: " + data.length);
}
}
```

Currently, when I try to run the program from the Owner.java class (as that's where the main method is), I'm getting an exception that says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The constructor ReadFile(String) is undefined
The method read() in the type ReadFile is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

The line it's complaining about is the line:

```
ReadFile rf = new ReadFile("Owner.data");
```

Could someone point out to me why I'm getting this exception, and what I've forgotten to do to avoid getting it? Many thanks in advance.

**Edit 25/09/2013**

So, I've tried editing my code to reflect the changes suggested by @sushain97 below, and I now have an 'Owner.java class that looks like this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Person {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ReadFile rf = new ReadFile("Owner.data");
    rf.read();

}
File f;
public String id;
public String lastName;
public String firstName;
public String street;
public String city;

public void readPerson() throws FileNotFoundException{
    //File f = new File("Smart Stream Associate Software Engineer (Java) - Bristol/assessment/src/Person.java");
    //InputStream IS = new FileInputStream(f);
}

}
```

and a ReadFile.java class that looks like this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile {
//File file;
String[] columns = new String[]{"personID", "lastName", "firstName", "street", "city"};
String[] data = new String[100];
private File file;


public ReadFile(String fileName){
    this.file = new File(fileName); 
}

public void read() throws IOException{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;

    int i = 0;
    while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
        data[i] = line;
        System.out.println(data[i]);
        i++;
    }
    br.close();

    String[] dataNew = new String[i];
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, dataNew, 0, i);
    data = dataNew;
    System.out.println("Data length: " + data.length);
}
}
```

However, when I run my code from the Owner.java class, I'm now getting an error that says:

`Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Owner.data (The system cannot find the file specified)`

and

```
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at ReadFile.read(ReadFile.java:15)
at Person.main(Owner.java:8)
```

I assume that this means that it cannot find the 'Owner.data' file- but this file is stored in the same folder as where my 'Owner.java' and 'ReadFile.java' classes are stored... any ideas why it cannot find the file, and how I can ensure that it does?

**Edit 25/09/2013 @ 09:45**

I've edited my code to show the changes suggested by PlanetSaro in their answer, as I understand them, so I now have:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFile {
static File file;
String[] columns = new String[]{"personID", "lastName", "firstName", "street", "city"};
String[] data = new String[100];

private static void readFile(String fileName){
    try{
        File file = new File("Person.data");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void read(File file2) throws IOException{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("Person.data");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;

    int i = 0;
    while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
        data[i] = line;
        System.out.println(data[i]);
        i++;
    }
    br.close();

    String[] dataNew = new String[i];
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, dataNew, 0, i);
    data = dataNew;
    System.out.println("Data length: " + data.length);
}
}
```

but I'm still getting an error that says `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Owner.data (The system cannot find the file specified)`

I don't understand why this is?

**Edit 25/09/2013 @ 10:35**

Ok, so I can't seem to get this working from any of the answers that have been given so far (that may well be just because I don't fully understand the answers- I've commented on them to that effect, so if that is the case, please explain them more fully (or basically- I am a beginner).

However, I have managed to reduce the amount of errors being displayed in the console when I run the program. My two classes now look like this:

ReadFile.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFile {
static File file;
String[] columns = new String[]{"personID", "lastName", "firstName", "street", "city"};
String[] data = new String[100];

private static void readFile(file){
    try{
        File file = new File("D:\\Users\\Elgan Frost\\Desktop\\careers\\Smart Stream Associate Software Engineer (Java) - Bristol\\assessment\\srcPerson.data");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file1);
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void read(File file2) throws IOException{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:\\Users\\Elgan Frost\\Desktop\\careers\\Smart Stream Associate Software Engineer (Java) - Bristol\\assessment\\srcPerson.data");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;

    int i = 0;
    while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
        data[i] = line;
        System.out.println(data[i]);
        i++;
    }
    br.close();

    String[] dataNew = new String[i];
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, dataNew, 0, i);
    data = dataNew;
    System.out.println("Data length: " + data.length);
}
}
```

Person.java:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Person {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ReadFile rf = new ReadFile();
    rf.read(ReadFile.file);

}
static File f;
public String id;
public String lastName;
public String firstName;
public String street;
public String city;

public void readPerson() throws FileNotFoundException{
    //File f = new File("Smart Stream Associate Software Engineer (Java) - Bristol/assessment/src/Person.java");
    //InputStream IS = new FileInputStream(f);
}

}
```

I am now only getting the one console error, which says:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error on token "file", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
    file cannot be resolved to a type"

and is complaining about line 9 in ReadFile.java, which is the line:

```
private static void readFile(file){
```

and line 7 in Person.java, which is the line:

```
ReadFile rf = new ReadFile();
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is, and how I can put it right?

Answer (score 0):

You've not declared a `ReadFile` constructor that can accept a `String` argument. You'll need one like below. While you are at it, add a `File` field which you can reuse when reading.

```
public class ReadFile {
    private File file;
    public ReadFile(String file) {
        this.file = new File(file);
    }
    ... 
    // use the following in your read() method
    // FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
}
```

You can then do

```
ReadFile rf = new ReadFile("Owner.data"); // "Owner.data" passed as an argument
```

You will also get an exception on the next line

```
rf.read("Owner.data");
```

since your `read()` method doesn't take any arguments either.

Use the value you passed to your constructor to select the file you want to read from.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the value I passed to my constructor, do you mean the name of the file that I want to read from? i.e. Owner.data? Would that be done in the `ReadFile rf = new ReadFile...` line of my Owner.java class?

Comment: @someone2088 Yes. That is a `String`. You need a constructor that accepts a String argument as described in my answer above.

Comment: So, I have the line `public ReadFile(String file)` as my constructor- do I need to set the value of 'file' to the name of the file I want to read from? i.e. `String file = "Owner.data"`? Where would I put this line?

Comment: @someone2088 Do you know how to instantiate an object (call a constructor with `new`)? You don't need to assign the value you want to a variable and pass that in. You could, but you don't need to. You can pass the value directly to the constructor.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? What would I need to do for this to solve me problem?

Comment: @someone2088 Look at my answer. Pass the `String` argument directly to the constructor call.

Answer (score 0):

It is because, the ReadFile object does not have a constructor argument with String type and also the method read() does not have any argument of type string passed in.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean here? I've edited my code to show the changes I think you mean, but I'm still getting the exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Owner.data (The system cannot find the file specified)` Could you give me a code example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a overloaded constructor to your `ReadFile` class definition. The default constructor (which is implicit and does not require declaration) does not take any arguments however you are trying to give it one, namely a `String`: `"Owner.data"`.

To fix this, you need to add a custom constructor to the `ReadFile` class like so:

```
public ReadFile(String fileName) //Constructor for a class has the same name as the Class
{
     //Define the fileObject that your read method needs to access to an instance variable
     this.file = new File(fileName); 
}
```

Of course, this requires declaring the variable:

```
private File file;
```

Finally, you need to access `file` set in the constructor inside the `read` method:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file); //file here refers to the variable set earlier
```

So, we end up with a slightly modified `ReadFile` class:

```
public class ReadFile {
    String[] columns = new String[]{"personID", "lastName", "firstName", "street", "city"};
    String[] data = new String[100];
    private File file;

    public ReadFile(String fileName) {
     this.file = new File(fileName); 
    }

    public void read() throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;

        int i = 0;
        while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
            data[i] = line;
            System.out.println(data[i]);
            i++;
        }
        br.close();

        String[] dataNew = new String[i];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, dataNew, 0, i);
        data = dataNew;
        System.out.println("Data length: " + data.length);
    }
}
```

Finally, usage would change from `rf.read("Owner.data")` to `rf.read()`.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. I've tried changing my code as you suggested, but I'm now getting the error `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Owner.data (The system cannot find the file specified)...` It's complaining about the line `FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);` in ReadFile.java, and the line `rf.read();` in Owner.java... any idea why this is, and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @someone2088, that means that the file `Owner.data` does not exist. Make sure that the generated `.class` file after compilation is in the same directory as the `Owner.data` file OR use an absolute path. For example: `C:\\projects\\workspace\\testing\\f1\\f2\\f3\\Owner.data`.

Comment: Hey, I've tried doing that, but still get the same compile error... any ideas why?

Comment: Did you specify an absolute path to the Owner.data file? Make sure the file already exists. Make sure that the program (your IDE) which spawned the Java process in the background has sufficient permissions to access the file. The error that you are experiencing now is a runtime error, not a compile error.